# Creating referenced keys within an array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, pass-by-reference

At the moment, my script creates referenced keys this:

```
<?php
$arr = array(
    'authority'      => $this->object->authority,
    'fragment'       => $this->object->fragment,
    'host'           => $this->object->host,
    'pass'           => $this->object->pass,
    'path'           => $this->object->path,
    'port'           => $this->object->port,
    'query'          => $this->object->query,
    'scheme'         => $this->object->scheme,
    'scheme_name'    => $this->object->scheme_name,
    'scheme_symbols' => $this->object->scheme_symbols,
    'user'           => $this->object->user,
);

$arr['domain']   = &$arr['host'];
$arr['fqdn']     = &$arr['host'];
$arr['password'] = &$arr['pass'];
$arr['protocol'] = &$arr['scheme'];
$arr['username'] = &$arr['user'];

ksort($arr);
return $arr;
```

**My question is:** there a better way to do this, possibly all in one go?

I know the below code doesn't work, but perhaps someone knows a better way?

```
<?php
$arr = array(
  'a' => '1',
  'b' => &$arr['a']
);
```

Comment: Firstly, What exactly do you want the code to do? And why?. We need background to be able to offer a solution.

Comment: Pass a key by reference the first example gets the job done, but I am asking if there is a better way. This all comes from a much larger class where having these passed by reference is important.

Comment: Are you asking how to shorten this code? If so, could you use a function like [`get_class_vars()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-class-vars.php) to get an array of all public properties of your class, then assign your array based on those?

Comment: @NickJ I rolled back to your original post since you say that having the variables passed by reference is important.

Comment: Sorry that's not an option, I need to recreate the array without making a reference to the original object. In short, I can't just copy the original object because of pre-existing references.

Comment: OK - to recreate the array without making a reference to the original object, are you looking to [clone your object?](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php)

Comment: If you really need to make a new array of your object, the only part I see you could shorten is: `$arr['domain'] = $arr['fqdn'] = &$arr['host'];`

Comment: @scrowler =) yep, you can upgrade that to an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I need to recreate the array without making a reference to the original object

You should use [object cloning](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php), which was introduced in PHP5. This will allow you to make a copy of your object with the current values, while allowing the original class to maintain any references to other variables already in place:

```
$arr = clone $this->object;
```

Variables will be accessible as class properties rather than array keys as in your example. If there's a problem with that for you, you could use something like [`get_class_vars()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-class-vars.php) to return an array of the properties of your class.